# nodejs mariadb query with expressions

Tags: sql, node.js, foreign-keys, mariadb, sql-insert

I'm trying to use the `connection.batch(sql, values)` function, but I always get an escaped query... how can I execute the request without escaping?

I need the unescaped values:

```sql
INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,a+b), (2,3,UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-a+b)...
```

but got:

```sql
INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,'a+b'), (2,3,'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-a+b')...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option puts the values in a derived table, that you can then  `select` from:

```
insert into test(a, b, c)
select x.a, x.b, x.a + x.b
from (select 1 a, 2 b) x
```

In very recent versions of MySQL we can use a row constructor:

```
insert into test(a, b, c)
select x.a, x.b, x.a + x.b
from (values (row (1, 2)) x(a, b)
```

Comment: i need query without escaped sql functions 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' => UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: @mat.twg: it is not possible in pure SQL. You would need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.